In Azure Devops Yaml pipeline, how to programatically add a step to a deployment
The company I'm at, has many Azure Devops YAML pipelines, spread across multiple Git repositories. These multi-stage pipelines are used to build .NET applications and to deploy them to four different stages (dev/test/accp/prod).
To reduce the amount of files being copied from one pipeline to the next, I've created a separate Git repo that contains reusable templates that the various pipelines can reference.
One of the templates is performing some cross-cutting concerns when deploying applications, and I want to extend this template to inject a preDeploy step for each jobs.deployment. To illustrate the problem, I've constructed a very contrived example consisting of 3 files. The first is a template that contains a deployment job; based on the parameter includePredeployStep a hard-coded preDeploy step will be included:
# File: deployJob.yaml
parameters:
- name: deploymentName
  type: string
- name: environment
  type: string
- name: includePredeployStep
  type: boolean

jobs:  
  - deployment: ${{parameters.deploymentName}}
    environment:
        name: ${{parameters.environment}}
        resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:      
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - powershell: | 
                Write-Host "Inside job deploy step"
        ${{if eq(parameters.includePredeployStep, 'true')}}:
          preDeploy:
            steps:
              - powershell: | 
                  Write-Host "Inside job preDeploy step"

To inject a preDeploy step, I've created another template that is heavily inspired on Microsoft's example of how to use each, this is the file that I cannot get to work:
# File: execute-deployment-jobs.yaml
parameters:
- name: deployJobs  
  type: jobList

jobs: 
- ${{ each job in parameters.deployJobs }}: 
  - ${{ each deployJobProperty in job }}:
      ${{ if and(ne(deployJobProperty.key, 'dependsOn'), ne(deployJobProperty.key,'strategy')) }}:
        ${{ deployJobProperty.key }}: ${{ deployJobProperty.value }}
      ${{ if eq(deployJobProperty.key, 'strategy')}}:        
        strategy:
          ${{if deployJobProperty.value.runOnce}}:
            runOnce: 
              ${{each runOnceProperty in deployJobProperty.value.runOnce}}: 
                ${{if ne(runOnceProperty.key, 'preDeploy')}}:
                  ${{runOnceProperty.key}}: ${{runOnceProperty.value}}                 
                preDeploy:
                  steps:
                  - powershell: | 
                      Write-Host "Inside injected preDeploy step"
                    displayName: Injected preDeploy step
                  - ${{each preDeployStep in runOnceProperty.predeploy.steps}}:
                    - ${{preDeployStep}}  

Finally, I use file 'execute-deployment-jobs' in my pipeline:
# File: pipeline.yaml
pool:
  name: Development  

stages:
- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - template: execute-deployment-jobs.yaml
    parameters:
      deployJobs:        
        - template: deployJob.yaml 
          parameters:
            deploymentName: MyApplication
            environment: Test
            includePredeployStep: false #  <--- Value 'false' does not cause a problem
        - template: deployJob.yaml 
          parameters:
            deploymentName: MyOtherApplication
            environment: Test
            includePredeployStep: true #  <--- Value 'true' causes the problem

When I validate the template, I get an error saying "'preDeploy' is already defined".
The problem only arises when includePredeployStep on the very last line in the pipeline is set to true; if I change the value to false, the validation of the template succeeds and the compiled template shows the injected preDeploy step.
Any suggestions on how I can modify file 'execute-deployment-jobs.yaml' such that it will work for jobs with or without build-in preDeploy steps?
Btw, much of the code in 'execute-deployment-jobs' must be duplicated for strategy canary and rolling. Don't know if there is a quick fix to solve that.
---------- Update 1 ----------
As a clarification; what I want of 'execute-deployment-jobs' is for it to always inject a preDeploy step into any deployment jobs, regardless
of whether the deployment job already has a preDeploy section. In the example pipeline, deployment of application 'MyOtherApplication' causes a compile error because it has a job-specific preDeploy section (that prints out "Inside job preDeploy step"). If I remove this job-specific preDeploy section, the template
can compile and both deployment jobs have an injected preDeploy section (printing out "Inside injected preDeploy step"). What causes the compile error?

The second template seems unnecessary/redundant to me, unless I am misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Steps can be injected in the first template. Are the developers able to set custom preDeploy steps or will these be always the same?

It seens that the attempt to nest preDeploy steps within another preDeploy section leads to conflicts.
I tested the issue and modified the execute-deployment-jobs.yaml. It will check if preDeploy already exists and merge the steps if it does, or create a new preDeploy section if it doesn't.
parameters:
- name: deployJobs  
  type: jobList

jobs: 
- ${{ each job in parameters.deployJobs }}: 
  - ${{ each deployJobProperty in job }}:
      ${{ if and(ne(deployJobProperty.key, 'dependsOn'), ne(deployJobProperty.key, 'strategy')) }}:
        ${{ deployJobProperty.key }}: ${{ deployJobProperty.value }}
      ${{ if eq(deployJobProperty.key, 'strategy') }}:        
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            ${{ each runOnceProperty in deployJobProperty.value.runOnce }}:
              ${{ if eq(runOnceProperty.key, 'preDeploy') }}:
                preDeploy:
                  steps:
                  - powershell: |
                      Write-Host "Inside injected preDeploy step"
                    displayName: Injected preDeploy step
                  - ${{ each preDeployStep in runOnceProperty.value.steps }}:
                      ${{ preDeployStep }}
              ${{ if ne(runOnceProperty.key, 'preDeploy') }}:
                ${{ runOnceProperty.key }}: ${{ runOnceProperty.value }}
            ${{ if not(deployJobProperty.value.runOnce.preDeploy) }}:
              preDeploy:
                steps:
                - powershell: |
                    Write-Host "Inside injected preDeploy step"
                  displayName: Injected preDeploy step


Test result:


If there is a list of predefined pre-deployment steps, the second template seems unnecessary/redundant to me (unless I am misunderstanding what you're trying to do).
Consider this sample pipeline:
trigger: none 

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
  - template: /pipelines/jobs/deployJob.yaml
    parameters:
      strategy: runOnce
      deploymentName: 'Dev'
      environment: 'Dev'

  - template: /pipelines/jobs/deployJob.yaml
    parameters:
      strategy: runOnce
      deploymentName: 'QA'
      environment: 'QA'
      includePredeployStep: true

deployJob.yaml can be implemented as follows:
parameters:
  - name: strategy
    type: string
    default: runOnce
    values:
      - runOnce
      - rolling
      - canary

  - name: deploymentName
    type: string

  - name: environment
    type: string

  - name: includePredeployStep
    type: boolean
    default: false

jobs:
  # based on the chosen strategy, include the corresponding template
  # e.g. runOnce-strategy-deploy-job.yaml
  - template: ${{ parameters.strategy }}-strategy-deploy-job.yaml
    parameters:
      deploymentName: ${{ parameters.deploymentName }}
      environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}

      # Using hard-coded steps for demonstration purposes only. 
      # Use templates instead to reuse steps in multiple jobs/pipelines.
      preDeploySteps: 
        - ${{ if parameters.includePredeployStep }}:
            #  hard-coded preDeploy step to include
            - powershell: | 
                Write-Host "This is the hard-coded step"
              displayName: 'Hard-coded predeploy step'
        
        # other preDeploy steps to include
        - powershell: | 
            Write-Host "This is preDeploy step 1"
          displayName: 'Predeploy step 1'
        - powershell: |
            Write-Host "This is preDeploy step 2"
          displayName: 'Predeploy step 2'

I am assuming that the predeploySteps will always be the same in this case, but the job can be more dynamic (e.g. adding another parameter with the list of steps to run).
Each strategy will have its correspondent job - e.g. runOnce-strategy-deploy-job.yaml:
parameters:
  - name: deploymentName
    type: string

  - name: environment
    type: string

  - name: preDeploySteps
    type: stepList

jobs:  
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.deploymentName }}
    environment:
      name: ${{ parameters.environment }}
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            # Using hard-coded steps for demonstration purposes only.
            # Use templates instead to reuse steps in multiple jobs/pipelines. 
            # Example:
            # - template: /pipelines/steps/deploy-steps.yaml
            - script: echo "This is a run-once deployment to ${{ parameters.environment }}"
              displayName: 'Run-once deployment to ${{ parameters.environment }}'
        ${{ if parameters.preDeploySteps }}:
          preDeploy:
            steps:
              - ${{ parameters.preDeploySteps }}

I haven't tested other strategies but implementation would be very similar to the above job - for example rolling-strategy-deploy-job.yaml:
parameters:
  - name: deploymentName
    type: string

  - name: environment
    type: string

  - name: preDeploySteps
    type: stepList

jobs:  
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.deploymentName }}
    environment:
      name: ${{ parameters.environment }}
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      rolling:
        maxParallel: 1
        deploy:
          steps:
            # Using hard-coded steps for demonstration purposes only.
            # Use templates instead to reuse steps in multiple jobs/pipelines. 
            # Example:
            # - template: /pipelines/steps/deploy-steps.yaml
            - script: echo "This is a rolling deployment to ${{ parameters.environment }}"
              displayName: 'Rolling deployment to ${{ parameters.environment }}'
        ${{ if parameters.preDeploySteps }}:
          preDeploy:
            steps:
              - ${{ parameters.preDeploySteps }}

Running the pipeline:


Thanks for the answer, but I wonder if you're addressing my second concern, which was only secondary to the question about the compile error.  My second template, 'execute-deployment-jobs' , is essential to what I try to achieve. This template is already being used to inject a dependsOn to the
jobs provided in parameter deployJobs, though as that that part works, I omitted it from my question.  Update the original question to further clarify the problem.

@SimonAx maybe I still don't understand exactly what you need, but I have the impression you're over-engineering your solution. Regarding the dependsOn why don't you add a parameter to the job templates that allows consumers to specify the dependencies? The same for other settings if required, such as conditions, job timeout, etc

Also note the official doc explains how to conditionally add steps at specific positions, which can be helpful:
# File: jobs/build.yml

parameters:
- name: 'preBuild'
  type: stepList
  default: []
- name: 'preTest'
  type: stepList
  default: []
- name: 'preSign'
  type: stepList
  default: []

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - script: cred-scan
  - ${{ parameters.preBuild }}
  - task: msbuild@1
  - ${{ parameters.preTest }}
  - task: vstest@2
  - ${{ parameters.preSign }}
  - script: sign

# File: .vsts.ci.yml

jobs:
- template: jobs/build.yml
  parameters:
    preBuild:
    - script: echo hello from pre-build
    preTest:
    - script: echo hello from pre-test

